# Одинаковые строки не совпадают

Tags: java, android

Я получаю с сервера ответ о регистрации. Если ответ 1 то логин свободен, если 0 то нет. В приложении проверяю этот ответ. Но то что мне приходит никак не хочет сравниваться.

```
` String resp = null;
        try {
            db.execute("registration.php", newacc);
            resp = db.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //test.setText(resp);
        if (!resp.equals("0")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Registration.this, Login.class));
        } else toast4.show();`
```

Я уже перепробовал все что мог но ничего не работает. Если приходит 0, то приложение все равно заходит в блок if и переходит на другую активити.
Вот еще PHP код

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
if (isset ($_POST['login'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['salt'],$_POST['reg_date'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['number'])){
    $login= $_POST['login'];
    $pass= $_POST['password'];
    $salt= $_POST['salt'];
    $reg_date= $_POST['reg_date'];
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $number= $_POST['number'];
    $querry0 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT login FROM account WHERE login = '$login'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($querry0) == 0){
        $querry1 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO account (login, password,salt, registration_date) VALUES ('$login', '$pass','$salt', '$reg_date')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $querry2 = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO client (client_name, phone_number, email) VALUES ('$name', '$number','$login' )") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        echo "1";
    }else echo "0";
}else echo "err";
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перевел строки в HEX: строка с сервера - efbbbf30, а с которой сравниваю - 30.При чем везде стоит кодировка в UTF-8. Как с этим быть?

Comment: После `?>` возможно стоит символ переноса строки, поэтому строка может получиться не `"0"`, а `"0\n"`

Comment: Перед `<?php` стоят пробелы, поэтому строка получается даже не `"0\n"`, а `"    0\n"`

Comment: После ?> нету переноса, а перед <? случайно здесь на сайте поставил пробелы

Comment: Возможно, ваш текстовый редактор просто не показывает перенос, а он на самом деле есть. Сотрите `?>` вообще, оно не нужно

Comment: Кто мешает посимвольно (и лучше - в hex)  вывести каждую строку и сравнить их глазами?

Comment: Выведите в лог переменную `resp`

Comment: Попробуйте: `if (!resp.equals("0")) {` -> `if (!resp.trim().equals("0")) {`

Comment: resp = "0" и все равно это получается true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php добавляет [`BOM`(Byte Order Mark)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) в Юникод.
Java, а следовательно Андроид при декодировании не удаляет его (уж не знаю почему) и надо это делать самому.
В Вашем случае нужен один символ (как я понял) и можно сравнить только его:

```
    if (resp.charAt(resp.length() - 1) != '0')) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Registration.this, Login.class));
    } else toast4.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем я теперь просто сравниваю строки в HEX. Костыль, но работает.